# Create A Directory Named With Current Date And Then Move Files Into It

Tags: unix

Good Afternoon All,

I'm looking to create a directory in CentOS 6.5 that is named after the current system date and then point newly created files into that new date directory.

So far, I've got "mkdir /home/`date +%Y%m%d`" but, I'm not sure about how to implement the mv command into this.

Best Regards

Aaron

Comment: Which files do you want to move? So what exactly do you want to put in the new folder?

Comment: I want to move newly-created graphics files into that new current date directory after they've been created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mv, symlink :) Point all your new files to `/somefolder/current` which is symlink to current day's folder, something in the lines of this at **start** of day

```
current_folder="/somefolder/"`date +%Y%m%d`
mkdir $current_folder
ln -fs /somefolder/current $current_folder
```

Alternatively, go with your current approach and move today's folders into the new folder, see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-list-todays-files-with-ls-and-find-command/ and do something like this at **end** of day:

```
current_folder="/somefolder/"`date +%Y%m%d`
mkdir $current_folder
mv `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -1` $current_folder
```